# pandas time information removed from datetime64[ns] column while printing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to sort pandas dataframe by column time of type datetime64.

Here is what I am trying to do.

[image]

I do not understand why it is removing the time information. Aby idea how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the rendering method `__repr__` in the DataFrame class. It is possible some of your rows have a time component of "00:00:00", so it is ignored in the output. It has nothing to do with `sort_values`.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': pd.date_range('1-1-2020 00:00:00', '1-1-2020 02:00:00', freq='H')})

df

                 time
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00
1 2020-01-01 01:00:00
2 2020-01-01 02:00:00

df

                 time
0 2020-01-01 00:00:00   # time component not ignored  
1 2020-01-01 01:00:00
2 2020-01-01 02:00:00

df.head(1)

        time
0 2020-01-01  # time component ignored because 
              # there are no other rows have a time component
```

Your output is correct. You'll also see the final output has rows not shown in the original sample.

Comment: yes, I did df.head(10) and I could see 00:00:00 . Thanks I am accepting the answer